# How to block for input in javascript

Tags: javascript, blocking

Conceptually what I need to do in javascript is the following:

```
// A) set up stuff

// B) collect values from input
do {
    var key = readKey();
    // do stuff like loading arrays, objects, etc based on this sequential input
} while (key != '.') // period signifies completion

// C) continue to do other stuff that can only be done once the arrays and objects from before are completely loaded.
```

I know that IO is non-blocking in javascript. So I have tried setting keyboard listeners and looping in a setTimeout construct, but I cannot avoid program execution flying through to C) and error-ing out because all of the prerequisite processing that is part of B) is not complete.

Here is what I tried:

```
// A) prepare stuff
var digrams = type() // B
// C) deal with digrams (errors out if digrams not complete)

function type() {
  var loopid;

  var loop = function() {
    // NOP
  };

  document.onkeypress = function (e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var char = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
    ...
    if (char=='.') {
     document.onkeypress = null;
     clearInterval(loopid);
     return digrams; // arr of obj composed thru key input
    }
  } // keylistener

  // Start the type loop
  loopid = setInterval( loop, 10);
}
```

I really need a way to work "against" javascript here. Any example code would be appreciated.

Comment: Or, you could work with the DOM's event-driven architecture. Have a `keyUp` listener that listens for `'.'`. When that fires, run the code in "C".

Comment: You're probably just thinking about this wrong. Don't block for input, handle the event of input. You said you tried listeners, but didn't show what you've tried.

Comment: Your question is pretty vague... You're mentioning some keyboard listeners and forgetting that a user have other methods of inputting values into fields (like i.e: Copy-Paste). You asked how to block an input element... block it against what exactly? Loaded arrays? Loaded Objects?... please clarify.

Comment: @MarkBordelon Edit the question. If you post the code in the comments, it will be illegible.

Comment: It is not possible to `return` from an event listener handler. Should  `digrams` be called only once?

Comment: ok. added a précis of my attempt at solution in the question.

Comment: As noted above, you can't return from a handler. Pass the data to a function at the end of the handler, and have it deal with it, or use Futures.

Comment: @guest271314: that return statement is used because the entire code is in a function. i'd like to return from the function only where the digrams array is complete, otherwise the line after the function call will error out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Promise`, to return a value asynchronously to `.then()`

```
// A) prepare stuff
var digrams = type();
digrams
.then(funcion handleSuccess(value) {
  // do stuff with `value` : `arr` passed to `resolve()`
}
, function handleError(err) {
  // handle error
}); // B
// C) deal with digrams (errors out if digrams not complete)

function type() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var loopid;

    var loop = function() {
      // NOP
    };

    document.onkeypress = function (e) {
      e = e || window.event;
      var char = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
      ...
      if (char=='.') {
        document.onkeypress = null;
        clearInterval(loopid);
        resolve(arr);
        // return digrams; // arr of obj composed thru key input
      }
      // reject(new Error("error message"));
    } // keylistener

    // Start the type loop
    loopid = setInterval( loop, 10);
  });
}
```

Comment: ok, even though i need a synchronous return from type(), the idea of promises sounds promising nonetheless..

Comment: Is there an update to this, now that keypress is deprecated?

Answer (score 0):

You could put the 'blocked' code into a function and then run that function once the keyup matches `.`

Something like:

```
function myContinue(){
   ...your blocked code
}

document.onkeypress = function (e) {
... assuming your keypress code is working
    if (char=='.') {
       myContinue();
    }
}
```

If you want to access variable outside the `continue` function, declare them outside the function:

```
var arrayToLoad;

function myContinue(){
  console.log(arrayToLoad);
}

document.onkeypress = function(e) {
   ...
   arrayToLoad.push(char);
   ...
      myContinue();
   ...
}
```

Alternatively you can pass the `vars` to the function

```
function myContinue(diagrams){
...
}

document.onkeypress = function(e) {
...
  myContinue(diagrams);
```

Comment: Shawn: this looks interesting to me, but the idea of having the type() function was to turn on the keylisteners, process digrams, turn off the keylisteners, and return the digrams. All of this is encapsulated into the behavior of the type() function. And only within that function should the keylisteners be active.

Comment: Gotcha... let me rethink the problem

Comment: I was about to mention `Promises` however @guest271314 beat me to it :)... I'd check that answer out